# Customizing Joomla 1.5 user registration process

Tags: joomla1.5

I am pretty new to joomla. I have been working on the maintenance of our company's website.
Coming to the issue, the website has a 2-step user registration process where users will fill up the registration form, once they submit, a verification mail will be sent to them with the activation link. Once they click on the activation link in their mail, they will be activated.
Now, since this is getting us a lot of junk users we want to change this process.
What we want to do is : 
When a user wants to register, he will be asked for his email-id.
Once the email is provided and submitted, a mail will be sent to him along with the activation link.
After the activation link is clicked he is brought to the website for further registration.
Only after this, the user will be put in our database as a valid user.

So basically, first I want to check if the email is a valid one and only then proceed with registration because email-ids are very important for our business

Please help.
Thanks in advance,
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

In the Database table where he will provide his email ID create a field namely "Status" that will only take Active and Inactive only. And you can use that to determine if user is active or not.